# Arithmetic of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

> If $z = \cos x + i\sin x$ , show that 
>   $$\frac{2}{1+z} =1-i\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right),$$

I get up to:
$$\frac{1+\cos x -i\sin x}{1+\cos x}.$$

Comment: Show what??????

Comment: What is the problem ? What have you tried, where are you stuck ?

Comment: I can't seem to get tanx/2, all i end up with is secx and tanx's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}\frac{2}{1+z}&=\frac{2(1+\overline{z})}{|1+z|^2}=\frac{2(1+\cos x - i\sin x)}{(1+\cos x)^2 + (\sin x)^2}\\
&=\frac{2(1+\cos x - i\sin x)}{2(1+\cos x)}=1-i\cdot\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}
\end{align*}
and recall the [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula).

Comment: I don't know what to do from here, I tried to divide by cosx

Comment: @SumeetSingh Expand the denominator and separate the real and the complex part of the fraction

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the [Weierstrass substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) (a bit of a misnomer, but that's how they're commonly known).

Note that if $\displaystyle t = \tan \frac x2$, then:

$$\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

and

$$\cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

So:

$$z = \frac{1}{1+t^2}(1-t^2 + i2t)$$

$$1 + z = \frac{1}{1+t^2}(1-t^2 + i2t) + \frac{1+t^2}{1+t^2} = \frac{2}{1+t^2}(1+it)$$

$$\frac{2}{1+z} = (1+t^2)\frac{1}{1+it} = (1+t^2)\frac{1-it}{1+t^2} = 1-it$$

as required.

Answer (score 1):

Showing that the two numbers are equal can be done by showing that the magnitude and the argument for both numbers are the same.

Magnitude:
$$1+z = 1+\cos x + i\sin x$$
$$|1+z| = \sqrt{1 + 2 \cos x + \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x} = \sqrt{2+2\cos x}$$
$$| \frac{2}{1+z}| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1 + \cos x}} $$
$$|1-it| = \sqrt{1+t^2} = \sqrt{1 + \tan^2(x/2)} = \sec (x/2)$$
And the two are the same by trigonometric identity

Argument:
$$ \arg(1+z) = \tan^{-1} \frac{\sin x}{1+ \cos x} = \tan^{-1} \tan (x/2) = x/2$$
$$ \arg(\frac{2}{1+z}) = - x/2$$
$$ \arg(1-it) = \tan^{-1} (-\tan (x/2) = -x/2$$